# How can vee-validate validates email and phone at the same time

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate

I have write a custom validator for phone and use it like this

### html

```
<template>
   <input type="text" name="username"  class="username" v-validate="'required|email|phone'">
</template>

<script>
import { MobileValidate } from '@/validates/MobileValidates'

Validator.extend('phone', MobileValidate);
</script>
```

### phone validate

```
const MOBILEREG = /^((1[3578][0-9])+\d{8})$/;

export const MobileValidate = {
    getMessage(field, args) {
        return 'phone is wrong';
    },
    validate(value, args) {
        console.log(MOBILEREG.test(value), value)
        return MOBILEREG.test(value);
    }
};
```

I want to validate the username is email or phone number, but it seems not work. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue that you're running into is that VeeValidate rules are all `AND` based; what this means is that `'required|email|phone'` is checking to see if the username field has a value AND it's an email AND it's a phone number.

To solve your problem, you'll want to use a completely custom rule alongside the `required` rule. This can be accomplished in the following way:

```
const phoneOrEmailRule = {
  getMessage(field, args) {
    return `The ${field} must be either a valid phone number or e-mail`;
  },
  validate(value, args) {

    // Custom regex for a phone number 
    const MOBILEREG = /^((1[3578][0-9])+\d{8})$/;

    // Check for either of these to return true
    return VeeValidate.Rules.email(value) || MOBILEREG.test(value);
  }
};
```

Once you've created your rule, you'll need to add it to the VeeValidate validator.

```
VeeValidate.Validator.extend('phoneOrEmail', phoneOrEmailRule);
```

Afterwards, you can add it to a field.

```
  <input type="text" name="username" v-model="username" class="username" v-validate="'required|phoneOrEmail'">
```

[Here's a CodePen that shows how it looks when it's working](https://codepen.io/mattjenkins/pen/VxmZwR?editors=1010). For testing, you can use any valid email that passes VeeValidate's normal email rule; when it comes to the phone number, it will be based off your regex so a value like `13112345678` would succeed.

Comment: Could you check this since the codePen is not working?

Comment: Hey @vojislav, I've pinned VeeValidate to a version around when this comment was originally posted, and it all works again. I don't use Vue or this lib that much day to day anymore, so things may (and I guess are since it errored out, haha) different for the Vue 3 + VeeValidate 4 combo.